# AWS Lambda function can’t get internet access while in custom VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

My Lambda function is assigned to  public subnet on custom VPC but can’t get internet access while other EC2 instances on the same subnet have internet access.

What am I missing?

P.S Security group and ACL are allowing all traffic in and out.

I have tried assigning elastic IP to functions network interface but that did not help.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [Give internet access to a Lambda function in a VPC](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/) your function must be in **private** subnet, not public. You also need a correctly setup route to a NAT gateway in a public subnet:

> Internet access from a **private subnet** requires network address translation (NAT). To give internet access to an Amazon VPC-connected Lambda function, route its outbound traffic to a **NAT gateway** or NAT instance in a **public subnet**.

Alternatively, do not associate your function with a VPC. This way, internet access will work out of the box.

Comment: Is it by design that Lambda function requires NAT to access internet from within the custom VPC?

Comment: @AndrewRyabchenko Yes. That's how aws choose to make it work.